# SQL Tough Queries

Tags: sql

Im trying to cram for an exam, and these are some of the toughest examples given

```
Movie(title, year, director, budget, earnings)
Actor(stagename, realname, birthyear)
ActedIn(stagename, title, year, pay)
CanWorkWith(stagename, director)
```

For each actor who acted in a movie in 2006, find their stage name and total pay in all
movies in which they have acted (i.e. including those not in 2006).

For each director who can work with at least 5 actors, find the total number of movies the
director has made in each year they have made a movie.

Comment: And heck, what's your question?

Comment: Instead of copy pasting the question show your approach. Else first learn sql and give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

You need to indulge in some TDQD — test-driven query design.

For the first question:

- How do you list actors who worked in a movie in 2006?
- Given such a list, how do you calculate the sum of each actor's pay in all the movies they ever worked in?
- Finding their stage name is easy since it seems to be the FK between relevant tables.

You need to know about sub-queries, and how to embed a sub-query in the FROM clause.  You may also need to know about table aliases.

For the second question:

- How do you calculate how many actors each director can work with?
- How do you restrict that list to the directors who can work with five or more actors? (HAVING)
- Given a list of directors (who can work with more than four actors), how do you count the number of movies the director made each year?  (GROUP BY, COUNT)

For any complex query, building up the query in stages is the way to go, especially if you can actually test your queries as you go.

Comment: Thanks ill keep these in mind when attempting these later